# Initialize only newly appended Elements in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am dynamically appending DOM elements inside `data-role = "header" or "footer" or "content"` using jquery.

What I am seeing that jquery mobile add some extra class during initialization. For example, if I have

`<h1>` inside `<div data-role="header">` then it will become `<h1 class="ui-title">`.

But when I dynamically add another `<h1>` inside `<div data-role="header">`, it will not add `class="ui-title"`.

Tried,

```
$(element).trigger('create'), $(element).page()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have found so fast which works for me,

```
$(document).page('destroy').page()
```